# Python elastic search cluster.health(wait_for_status='yellow', request_timeout=1800) returns after 30 sec with TransportError(408)

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm writing a python script the loads a backup to an index.
I want my script to wait until the cluster is healthy again (at least yellow).
It usually takes over 15 minutes.

I tried doing

```
es.cluster.health(wait_for_status='yellow', request_timeout=1800)  # 30 minutes
```

But I get

> TransportError(408).

I also tried without `request_timeout` but that gives me:

> ConnectionTimeout caused by - ReadTimeoutError().

I also tried to change the connection

```
es = Elasticsearch(es_hosts, retry_on_timeout=True, timeout=1800)
```

Same 408 error...

Thanks!